# ResponseText that comes back from ajax is not equal to php text

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, logic, responsetext

Heres the issue. I have an an ajax function that is just checking if an email that a user inputs is already used.

The php script that it uses either sends back "true" or "false" strings depending on the result. When i get the response text back, or the "data" variable in the below function, and see if its == to "true" it never passes and always evaluates to false.

> This is odd, because when I have printed out the data variable on
>   screen it shows as "true" when it should, but its just not being shown
>   as equal to "true" in the if statement. No idea what is happening
>   here.

AJAX FUNCTION:

```
function check_email() {
  var email = document.sign_up_form.email_first.value;
  document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML = ' <img src="loading.gif" width="15">';
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "java_check_email.php",
        data: "email="+email,
        success: function(data){
              if(data == "true"){
              document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML = ' <img src="check.png" width="15">';
              document.getElementById("email4").innerHTML = '';  
              }
              else {
              document.getElementById("email1").innerHTML = ' <img src="xmark.png" width="15">';
              document.getElementById("email4").innerHTML = 'Email is already in use<br>';    
              }
     }
});
```

}

UPDATE:

PHP script looks like this

```
    <?php
include('functions.php');

$email = $_GET['email'];

$query_check = "removed for obvious reasons...";

$result_check = mysql_query($query_check);

if(mysql_num_rows($result_check) == 0){
echo 'true';
}
else{
echo 'false';
}

?>
```

Also, after calling console.log(data) when the ajax response is received i got a value of "true" in the js console.....

Comment: What does the php look like and what does `console.log(data);` give you?

Comment: are you sure data is actually a string? are you doing echo "true"; in your php script or echo true;?

Comment: For debugging, try `if (data.replace(/\s+/g, '') == "true") {`. My money is on whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags. Also if you want to return a boolean to JS you should simply echo `1` or `0`, so you can just do `if (data) {` (but you'll still need to sort out the whitespace issue before this will work)

Comment: Following your edit, make sure the `<` of the opening `<?php` tag is the very first character in the file, also make sure that if your editor uses UTF-8, it is set to use UTF-8 *without* BOM. Remove the closing `?>` tag completely as it is not required.

Comment: Try adding `cache:false` to your ajax request options. Your XHR might be cached by browser with old value.

Comment: must have been the whitespace because the regex replace method fixed it. Thanks so much. I cant call your comment the answer since its not in the answer section i guess? If you move it i will

Comment: Did you check for `whitespace` issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging, try

```
if (data.replace(/\s+/g, '') == "true") {
```

...my money is on whitespace outside the `<?php ?>` tags. Note that if this solves the problem it should not considered the solution - the real solution is to remove the additional whitespace from the PHP script.

The `<` of the opening `<?php` tag should be the very first character in the file. For example:

```
          This empty line will be output directly
    <?php
^^^^ This whitespace will be output directly
```

Note also that the closing `?>` tag is often unnecessary (as it seems to be in this case) and omitting it completely can help avoid problems like this.

If you want to return a boolean to JS you should simply echo `1` or `0`, so you can just do this in the receiving Javascript:

```
if (data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've had the exact same problem and couldn't fix it. I am realy sure it wasn't a white-space issue but I was able to solve it in a different way.
Maybe it's not the best way (I still want to know why it doesnt work in the usual way), but what I did was echo a 0 (for false) and a 1 (for true)

Then I parsed the data to an Integer, so my code looks like this:

```
function(data){
        var result = parseInt(data);
        if (result === 1){
             $('#loginresult').html('OK');
        } else {
            $('#loginresult').html('NOT OK');
        }
```

I hope I can help anyone with this workaround (but a good solution would be better)